# Which is faster in terms on overall execution speed

Tags: php, mysql, database, ftp

I'm currently optimizing an application's login process' caching and I'm thinking of using a File based approach, but I'm not so sure if it's the best when it comes to speeding things up. So among the following approach, which would greatly improve my application?

- PHP_SESSION
- Filebased(physical file)
- PDO_Database
- FTP

Comment: Could you give more details about your potential solutions? I don't see how FTP could help you with a login-process!

Comment: use a database - files can get corrupted, ftp is not a solution in any sense and php sessions should be used after db access

Answer (score 0):

Anything that touches files is less optimal for caching than when staying in memory. Respectively anything that goes via a network is generally even slower. So when it comes to speed you're probably best off using the PHP_SESSION.

Do note however that because it is memory based you also lose the cache when the application or the server is restarted. If this is undesired you should probably go for a file based solution.

Comment: Tried this suggestion but it took 5 times longer than the file base approach. The delay is due to the session start/construction.
result of session base = 4.09sec
result of file base = 809ms
Is there another way to improve the result for the session base approach?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with how exactly session works in PHP as I'm more an ASPNET developer myself. But a 4s delay in accessing the session seems very peculiar to me. Are you sure it's not just a one time setup cost associated with the startup of the application?

Comment: Yes, it's a one time cost (during 1st login).
Is there a  way to speed up the 1st session setup process?